# Setting up environment for python MapScript development

Tags: python, installation, mapserver, mapscript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to setup a virtual environment for developing against the Python bindings of MapScript on Windows. So far, I've tried several things in various combinations:

- Install MapScript via pip using the instructions provided [here](https://pypi.org/project/mapscript/), installing MapServer provided by GISInternals
- Installing MapScript via pip and using the MS4W package
- Obviously registering MapServer in `%PATH%`
- ... but also setting `%MAPSERVER_DLL_PATH%` according to recent changes for python > 3.8 as can be seen in [this commit here](https://github.com/MapServer/MapServer/pull/6222/commits/a49cfbd3271b37008034b6753823c575ec15bb15#diff-2115257f208959f8512ac695cb235104d11071b0e996cdbee1a1da4372f49267R21).
- I tried both with standard installations of Python3.7, Python3.8 and also the Python3.7 supplied by OSGeo4W.

However no matter what I do, I'm always running into the following error:

```
  File "c:\Users\admin\source\repos\QGISToMapFileConv\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mapscript
  File "c:\Users\admin\source\repos\QGISToMapFileConv\.venv\lib\site-packages\mapscript\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .mapscript import *
  File "c:\Users\admin\source\repos\QGISToMapFileConv\.venv\lib\site-packages\mapscript\mapscript.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _mapscript
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

The readme package [here](https://github.com/MapServer/MapServer/tree/main/mapscript/python) indicates that the error basically means MapServer.dll cannot be found.

What else could be tried here? I can verify that the runtime should be able to access all paths.

Comment: is your python and mapscript 32-bit, if not it may not work with ms4w.

Comment: You had a tag for QGIS but made no mention of how that is relevant to your question so I’ve removed it.

Comment: @nmtoken Interesting idea. I've create a new env with 32-bit python and installed the corresponding mapscript with pip. However when trying to import, it yields the following issue: `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _mapscript: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` If that should be because mapscript is still 64-bit, I'm not entirely sure how to force install the 32-bit release.

Comment: I may have misread your question, I see you have tried multiple ways.  MS4W is 32bit application, so if you use it then I think everything needs to be 32bit.  But if you used the 64bit mapserver from gisinternals, 64 bit python + mapscript.dll, 64bit Apache then I assume that's not your issue.